# Multiplication trigger within a table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table salesOrderItems:

```
soItemID           INT(11)         PK
salesOrderID       INT(11)
productID          INT(11)
cost               DECIMAL(7,2)
qty                TINYINT(2)
extendedCost       DECIMAL(8,2)
```

Via PHP, user is presented with a form to enter productID (via drop down), that selection then populates the cost field.  User then enters qty.  `extendedCost` is not visible on form.

What I want is a trigger that should simply auto-calculate/insert `extendedCost` (i.e. - multiply cost x qty) and populate `extendedCost`, but I'm getting 1064 errors.

Here's the trigger - what the hell am I missing???  I swear I've done this 20 times:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS EXTENDEDCOST $$

CREATE TRIGGER EXTENDEDCOST AFTER INSERT ON salesOrderItems FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE salesOrderItems
    SET extendedCost = (cost * qty)
    WHERE soItemID = NEW.soItemID;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Result:

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-db' at line 1

SQL Statement:

USE <my db/schema>



ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.



ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-db' at line 1

SQL Statement:

USE <my db/schema>
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, but it's driving me nuts and I'm completely stuck and need extra eyes...

Thanks guys, in advance!

Comment: The error is elsewhere, the message is complaining about a "use ..." statement and you're probably just missing some backticks around the database name.

Comment: execute this query in phpmyadmin after selecting a DB not directly

Comment: I thought the same thing - use error...line 1....  But there's nothing odd about my command.  I don't have phpmyadmin loaded so I can't try that..I'm using workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to insert a calculated value, why perform an extra update and not set trigger time *BEFORE INSERT* :

```
CREATE TRIGGER EXTENDEDCOST BEFORE INSERT ON salesOrderItems FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.extendedCost = NEW.cost * NEW.qty
END $$
```

See also this answer [mysql 'after insert' trigger to calculate a field based on other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942052/mysql-after-insert-trigger-to-calculate-a-field-based-on-other-fields) .