# MySQL Trigger Update Failes even after using NEW. to specify field

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that 'on insert populates field `foo` to either 'set_to_1' or 'set_to_2' based on the value of field `bar` on the same insert.  I am getting back error:

**ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'my_table' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**

I did some research on this error and all the solutions I found point to issues where the original statement didn't specify the `NEW.field_name` when checking/updating the field name on the insert.  I believe I am already doing that.

Other questions/answers that I reviewed are at these two links but these seem to indicate I was doing it correctly.

[mysql 'after insert' trigger to calculate a field based on other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942052/mysql-after-insert-trigger-to-calculate-a-field-based-on-other-fields)

http://crazytoon.com/2008/03/03/mysql-error-1442-hy000-cant-update-table-t1-in-stored-functiontrigger-because-it-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-this-stored-functiontrigger/

```
CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER `compare`.`trigger_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_database`.`my_table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF  NEW.foo IS NULL OR
   NEW.foo LIKE ''
THEN
   IF (NEW.bar LIKE 'test1'
      OR NEW.bar LIKE 'test2')
   THEN
SET NEW.foo = 'set_to_1';
   ELSE
      SET NEW.foo = 'set_to_2';
   END IF;
END IF;
```

END

Comment: the first one is using AFTER insert and you should change yours to use after insert aswell. Manipulating fieldvalues that way is evil (why not declare that in your INSERT already?)

Comment: Interesting.. In that first example the original poster was using 'after insert' and the selected answer was to make it 'before insert'

When I try to adjust my query to AFTER I get back

"Error Code: 1362
Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger"

Comment: well, its a question of taste. I like AFTER ones more because people have to write "UPDATE" in the trigger (since the dataset is written already) and might get the idea its better to let the application layer handle the logic. The biggest downfall is performance. Insert triggers another update on the same dataset. Anyway why do you need that in your table anyways? cant the retriving side calculate that uppon select instead?