# SQL use trigger during insert for calculating value in one table

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two tables, first with parts, second with orders. In orders i store IDPart and quantity of this part.
I would like achieve that when inserting the IDPart and Quantity values ​​into the Orders, the trigger automatically fires up to calculate the price.
Did someone can help to figure it out?

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE Parts
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,               
    PartName NVARCHAR(70),
    Price DECIMAL(6,2)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,   
    IDPart INT REFERENCES Parts(ID),
    Quantity INT,
    Price DECIMAL(6,2)
)
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Also think about what should happen if `parts.price` changes afterwards.

Comment: Oh and [edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, what you want to do is:

- Create a trigger
- Establish when it should trigger - Insert & update
- Create a function which runs each time an update or insertion is made

***Please be aware that I am only experienced with PL/pgSQL (PostgresSQL), so that's the language of the function.***

## Creating a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertOrder    
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE functionSetOrderPrice();
```

This trigger is called insertOrder, and will trigger the function "functionSetOrderPrice()" whenever we insert or update a row in the Orders-table.

## Creating the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION functionSetOrderPrice()
RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
  -- Getting the particular part's price
  part_price := (SELECT price FROM Parts WHERE Parts.ID=NEW.IDPart);

  -- Multiplying the price with the quantity to get order total price
  order_price := part_price * NEW.quantity;

  -- Let's set the Orders.price to the correct value!
  NEW.price = order_price;
  return NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Some things to be mindful of, and can help you and others understand your database is to stick to these principles:

- Table-names should always be plural and capitalized: **Parts, Orders, Users**
- Attribute-names should always be lower-case and singular: **quantity, name, id**

Also, if you were looking for triggers for MySQL, the syntax is slightly different, but the thought-process is the same. [Here's a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942052/mysql-after-insert-trigger-to-calculate-a-field-based-on-other-fields).

Comment: Thx, i will try convert this to MSSMS language

Comment: Also, good You shared a good example, I don’t know why I don’t found this before asking. thx again

Comment: No problem, I found [this resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMSProcedure) which could be useful. :)